# Luhn Check Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to have someone input there credit card number and validate if it is a valid number by doing the Luhn Check. I want to be able to check it if they input the whole card number as one big string or if they put spaces in it. In my function validate though I keep getting an error message that there is an illegal return statement for my total variable. Here is my current code.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(numbers) {
        var sum;
        var sum1;
        var total;
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers.length % 2 == 0) {
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
            else
                if ((numbers[i] * 2) >= 10) {
                    sum1 += numbers[i] - 9;
                }
                else
                    sum1 += numbers[i];
        }
        total = sum + sum1;
        return total;
    }

    function cardnumber() {
        var cardnumber = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var numbers = cardnumber.split(" ");
        var out = "";


        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            out += validate(numbers[i]);

            if (out % 10 == 0)
                return true;
        }
    }

    function getOutput() {
        if (cardnumber()) {
            alert("You card is valid.");
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <h1>I will validate a credit card number</h1>
    Card Type:
    <input type="radio" id="c1" value="Visa">Visa</input>
    Card number: <textarea id="input" style="vertical-align: middle;"></textarea></br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getOutput()" /></br></br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `validate` is missing an opening curly brace after the for loop. This made your return statement outside of your function and since a return statement is invalid outside of a function it was an invalid return statement.

```js
function validate(numbers){
    var sum;
    var sum1;
    var total;
    for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) { // this previous curly brace `{` was missing 
            if (numbers.length%2==0){
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
            else
                if ((numbers[i]*2)>=10){
                    sum1 += numbers[i] -9;
                }
                else
                    sum1 +=numbers[i];
    }
    total = sum + sum1;
    return total;
}
```

**EDIT WITH MORE CORRECTIONS**:

There is quite a bit more wrong with the formatting of you functions you also need to include opening and closing curly braces around your other `else` statements. I would suggest getting a code editor like VS Code and downloading an extension similar to [Bracket pair colorizer 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2). It will highlight paired brackets together. This will help you with your formatting.

```js
function validate(numbers){
    var sum;
    var sum1;
    var total;
    for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers.length%2==0){
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
            else {
                if ((numbers[i] * 2) >= 10) {
                    sum1 += numbers[i] - 9;
                }
                else {
                    sum1 += numbers[i];
                }
            }
    }
    total = sum + sum1;
    return total;
}

function cardnumber(){
    var cardnumber= document.getElementById("input").value;
    var numbers = cardnumber.split(" ");
    var out ="";


    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        out += validate(numbers[i]);
    }
    if (out %10==0)
        return true;
}
function getOutput() {
    if (cardnumber()) {
        alert("You card is valid.");
    }
}
```

These are all the changed lines (the left is new code and the right side is the old code):

[image]

### Tips for completion

#### validate function

So, currently if you console.log your `numbers` are strings when they pass into the validate function. This is fine when they are sent into validate, but when you add the `numbers` at index `i` (i.e. `numbers[i]`) you should use `parseInt(numbers[i], 10)` to turn them into numbers, so for example `sum += parseInt(numbers[i], 10);` the same applies when adding to `sum1`. The other thing to note is that saying `var sum` will make `sum` equal the `undefined` value. When you add a number or string to an undefined value some unexpected things will probably happen, so since you need your sums and totals to be numbers you should instead initialize your sums and totals at 0. Like so:

```
var sum = 0;
var sum1 = 0;
var total = 0;
```

The only other thing wrong with your `validate` function is that your are checking if `numbers.length%2==0` which instead you should be checking if `i%2==0`. You may have to think about why for a moment, but one thing you may notice is the length of `numbers` never changes during the iteration of the loop where as `i` does change at each step.

#### cardnumber function

Your `out` variable needs to be initialized to zero. Your cardnumber can instead be split by spaces and then joined by the empty string. This handles if the user accidentally types multiple spaces. Then since you join your split array you no longer would need a for loop.

```
var numbers = cardnumber.split(" ").join('');
var out =0;

out += validate(numbers);
```

#### Lines that need changing somehow

Here's a difference of the lines of the old code that where incorrect and need to be changed somehow. I'm not giving you the completed code, but hopefully this will be sufficient to help you figure out the rest on your own (I feel I shouldn't give you all of the solution due to some degree of academic integrity. I would feel I robbed you the opportunity to learn more if I don't at least let you think through and type it out on your own.). If you are wondering what needs to be changed on a specific line that is highlighted red all of it should be above, so best of luck.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your help. Right now I am just using Notepad++ for my editor and just inspecting in my browser when the page doesnt do what I want it to do for debugging. You have been very helpful on my homework and I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Edit: My code fully works now, my validate function's algorithm is wrong though as even when I try to type in a valid card number it is still saying its not right

Comment: @fahnz okay I'll attempt to help you a little more. Do you know how to debug your code in the developer tools? You could try adding in `console.log()` statements.

Comment: @fahnz also, you could try to learn to use your browser's debugger. It will allow you to stop on lines and see the values they have.

Comment: @fahnz I'll try to give you some tips to complete your assignment and show you which lines have bugs in them.

Comment: @fahnz I added some extra info to help you, but it's late in my timezone, so I'm going to bed now. Best of luck in learning JavaScript, it has some weird quirks, but it's a great language and hopefully you enjoy it.